# binding asp:checkboxlist in asp:datalist c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, datalist, checkboxlist

I have `asp:datalist` binding from table this table contain two columns one of them `string` and the other is `list<string>`

I am binding the string value in `<div>` and I want to bind the `list<string>` in asp:CheckBoxList How Can I do this in html or .cs ?

this is html part

```
<asp:DataList ID="feedbacklist" RepeatDirection="Vertical" runat="server" Width="100%">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div class="rowstyle2" style="width: auto">
                    <%# Eval("Question")%>
            </div>
            <div class="news_des">
             <asp:CheckBoxList ID="answerslist" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" Width="100px">
             </asp:CheckBoxList>
            </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:DataList>
```

this is c# part in page load

```
List<string> boollist = new List<string>();
        List<string> stringlist = new List<string>();
        boollist.Add("Yes");
        boollist.Add("No");
        stringlist.Add("1");
        stringlist.Add("2");
        stringlist.Add("3");
        DataTable test = new DataTable();
        test.Columns.Add("Question", typeof(string));
        test.Columns.Add("Answers", typeof(List<string>));
        test.Rows.Add("What do you think of our new website?", boollist);
        test.Rows.Add("What do you think so?", stringlist);
        feedbacklist.DataSource = test;
        feedbacklist.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<asp:DataList ID="feedbacklist" RepeatDirection="Vertical" runat="server" Width="100%">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <div class="rowstyle2" style="width: auto">
                            <%# Eval("Question")%>
                    </div>
                    <div class="news_des">
                     <asp:RadioButtonList ID="answerslist" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" DataSource='<%# Eval("Answers")%>'>
                     </asp:RadioButtonList>
                    </div>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:DataList>
```

Answer (score 2):

Three things you may wish to look at:

1. Use a [BindingList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679.aspx)
2. Add a [BindableAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.bindableattribute.aspx) to your *Name* property
3. Binding to a CheckListBox 
   [Binding DropDownList, ListBox and CheckBoxList Control the ADO.NET way](http://geekswithblogs.net/dotNETvinz/archive/2009/02/24/binding-dropdownlist-listbox-and-checkboxlist-control-the-ado.net-way.aspx)